# Swift вывод данных без нажатия на кнопку

Tags: swift, swift4

Здраствуйте, давно уже занимаюсь Swift, и не давно писал програмку и мне там надо было выводить в Label определенные данные при условии что данные могут меняться(тоесть нельзя просто в storyboard в label текст вести и все, надо через код) тоесть вот заходит пользователь в программу и ему выводятся какие то данные которые он вводил раньше(не путайте, вопрос не связан с сохранением данных в файл ) и у меня только получилось что бы ввысьи данные мне приходилось делать специальную кнопку что бы при нажатии на нее выводились искомые данные. А как сделать так что бы данные сразу были видны без опреденныэ нажатий. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, и Вам нужно, чтобы в лэйблах появившегося вью контроллера уже был какой-то текст, то просто присвойте значение (нужный Вам текст) свойству yourLabelOutlet.text перед появлением вью контроллера и всё. Например в методе viewDidLoad().

Answer (score 0):

Поместите ваш код по нажатию кнопки в viewDidLoad или viewWillAppear

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // ваш код 
}
```